# Django refresh/reload Self referenced model

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

I am trying to write my model in Django 1.8, but I am facing an issue when adding an entry which references another entry. I explain:

This is my model:

```
class Store(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    description = models.TextField()
    parentStore = models.ForeignKey('self')
```

This is my serializer:

```
class StoreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    choices=[(e.id,e.title) for e in Store.objects.all()]

    if choices == []:
        choices=[(1,None)]
    parent = serializers.ChoiceField(source='parentStore_id',choices=choices)    

    class Meta:
        model = Store
        fields = ('id','title','description', 'parent')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        store = Store.objects.create(title=validated_data['title'],
                                     parentStore_id=validated_data['parentStore_id'],
                                     description=validated_data['description'])
        return store
```

I am able to add a Store to my database using the API, and this is the response:

```
HTTP 201 Created
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS

{
    "id": 334,
    "title": "***0000000",
    "description": "555555555",
    "parent": 330
}
```

However, when I add new Store juste after referencing this node (subStore), I face an error.
The request:

```
{
    "title": "***0000000",
    "description": "555555555",
    "parent": 334
}
```

The response:

```
HTTP 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS

{
    "parent": [
        "\"334\" is not a valid choice."
    ]
}
```

It seems that my serializer is not automatically refreshed with the new value.
When I restart Django and replay exactly the same request, my entry is added successfully.

Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your choices are loaded once when the serialiser is loaded, not for every request. Try using [`PrimaryKeyRelatedField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield) instead.

```
parent = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(source='parentStore_id')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this propably can resolve my issue, but how can I force some custom choices? as I do:
choices=[(e.id,e.title) for e in Store.objects.all()] or choices=[(1,None)]

Comment: I am expecting a quick reload of this choices by overriding the create, update or __init__? is that possible or should I re-think  my model ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the rest framework internals, so I don't know how to dynamically update the choices. You could try asking on the [rest framework mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/django-rest-framework) (post here if you get an answer!)